# Login loop, black screen problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, crash, graphic-card

The `login loop` problem that has been affecting Ubuntu distributions for years, but I have found posts on the Internet about the same, or similar, problems in other distributions too. Most of what I've read says that it is a problem with the nvidia driver which is not compatible with `nvidia` or `AMD` graphics cards. [This page](https://linuxconfig.org/fixing-black-screen-after-suspension-in-ubuntu-22-04-nvidia-amd-guide) is one description of it.

It has been reported for at least 7 years, and I am wondering if there are any websites that document which versions of which distributions using which graphics cards and drivers cause this to happen. It is a critical problem because it can render the system unusable, which it has in my case. On a work computer, I need a 100% stable system. I prefer Linux, but I think this problem affects all distributions now.

Does anyone know of any online resources that list what systems, graphics cards, etc. are, or are not, affected by this? Since the problem can re-occur any time an upgrade is done, it comes back again even if you try to fix it. So I would like to get a system that does not have any hardware components that are incompatible with the nvidia driver. How can I be sure that a system I might buy will always work even if I do upgrades that automatically switch me to an nvidia driver?